# Group Barplot failure

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am looking at analysing data in R from a YouGov survey looking at variables and then comparing them with the US states the respondents are from.

E.g.

```
                repimmigration
states           Much.less Somewhat.less      Same Somewhat.More Much.More
  Alabama        12.500000     10.000000 25.000000     22.500000 30.000000
  Alaska         25.000000     25.000000  8.333333     16.666667 25.000000
  Arisona        12.820513     17.094017 11.965812     17.094017 41.025641
  Arkansas       12.000000      6.000000 18.000000     22.000000 42.000000
  California     21.985816     10.638298 21.276596     16.548463 29.550827
  Colorado       20.588235     20.588235 17.647059     14.705882 26.470588
  Connecticut    14.285714     23.809524 16.666667     21.428571 23.809524
```

then I added rowSums to make the 5 'repimmigration' into 3 ' Easier, Same, Harder'

```
                   Less      Same     More
Alabama        22.50000 25.000000 52.50000
Alaska         50.00000  8.333333 41.66667
Arisona        29.91453 11.965812 58.11966
Arkansas       18.00000 18.000000 64.00000
California     32.62411 21.276596 46.09929
Colorado       41.17647 17.647059 41.17647
Connecticut    38.09524 16.666667 45.23810
Delaware       36.36364 36.363636 27.27273
```

I am trying to pick out 6 specific states 'Iowa, Ohio, Pennsylvania, Wisconsin, Michigan, Florida' and put them into a group bar plot. 
However whenever I try to it doesnt group together at all, I know there is a fault to my process I just can't figure out where. the problem seems to stem from the 'rowSums' function being added.

Here is my script:

```
Rep.immig.states=prop.table(table(states,repimmigration),1)*100
rep.im.sum = data.frame(Less=rowSums(Rep.immig.states[,1:2]), Same=Rep.immig.states[,3], More=rowSums(Rep.immig.states[,4:5]))

statesrepim = data.frame(Iowa=rep.im.sum['Iowa',1:3], Florida=rep.im.sum['Florida',1:3], Michigan=rep.im.sum['Michigan',1:3], Ohio=rep.im.sum['Ohio',1:3], Pennsylvania=rep.im.sum['Pennsylvania',1:3], Wisconsin=rep.im.sum['Wisconsin',1:3])

barplot(as.matrix(statesrepim),beside=T)
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible, i.e. post code that gets the dataset from its url? Or else post the output of `dput()` on the dataset, for some states?

Comment: When you say *"pick out 6 specific states and put them into a group bar plot"*, that doesn't sound like "grouping" in the ggplot sense. Just selecting/filtering rows in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be using the base plot? The following uses `ggplot2`:

```
# Load your toy data
df <- read.table(text = "Less      Same     More
Alabama        22.50000 25.000000 52.50000
Alaska         50.00000  8.333333 41.66667
Arisona        29.91453 11.965812 58.11966
Arkansas       18.00000 18.000000 64.00000
California     32.62411 21.276596 46.09929
Colorado       41.17647 17.647059 41.17647
Connecticut    38.09524 16.666667 45.23810")

# Load packages
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")

tidy_df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(state = rownames(df)) %>% 
  gather(key='category', value = "value", -state)

# Plot your data group bar plots
ggplot(tidy_df, aes(category, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = state),
          position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

If you want to plot only certain states, you simply subset your data before plotting like so:

```
tidy_df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(state = rownames(df)) %>% 
  gather(key='category', value = "value", -state) %>%
  filter(state %in% c("Alabama", "Connecticut"))

ggplot(tidy_df, aes(category, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = state),
           position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider continuing to use base R's `barplot`:

**Data** *(below graphs assume this structure)*

```
txt <- '                   Less      Same     More
Alabama        22.50000 25.000000 52.50000
Alaska         50.00000  8.333333 41.66667
Arizona        29.91453 11.965812 58.11966
Arkansas       18.00000 18.000000 64.00000
California     32.62411 21.276596 46.09929
Colorado       41.17647 17.647059 41.17647
Connecticut    38.09524 16.666667 45.23810
Delaware       36.36364 36.363636 27.27273'

df <- read.table(text=txt, header = TRUE)
```

**Graph**

```
# OPEN TO FILE FOR WRITING
png("/path/to/my/graph.png", width = 800, height = 350)

  # INITALIZE CANVAS
  layout(c(1,2), heights=c(7,1))

  # BAR PLOT
  par(mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))

  barplot(as.matrix(df), col=rainbow(nrow(df)), main="State Value Bar Graph",
          beside=TRUE, cex.axis=0.8, ylim=c(0,80), ylab="Value")

  # LEGEND
  par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  plot.new()
  legend("top", legend=row.names(df), fill=rainbow(nrow(df)), ncol=nrow(df))

dev.off()
```

[image: Plot Output]

---

For specific states, simply index the `row.names`. See use of *states* vector adjusting the color palette (*rainbow*) accordingly:

```
  # INITALIZE CANVAS
  layout(c(1,2), heights=c(7,1))

  # BAR PLOT
  par(mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4))
  states <- c("Arizona", "California", "Delaware")

  barplot(as.matrix(df[states,]), col=rainbow(length(states)), main="State Value Bar Graph",
          beside=TRUE, cex.axis=0.8, ylim=c(0,80), ylab="Value")

  # LEGEND
  par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  plot.new()
  legend("top", legend=row.names(df[states,]), fill=rainbow(length(states)),
         ncol=nrow(df[states,]))
```

[image: Subset Plot Output]